# List all files in folder in shared Google Team Drive using PyDrive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I'm trying to use PyDrive to get a list of all file ids in a Google Drive Folder. My query works when I use it on a folder within my drive but doesn't work when I try to use it on a folder in a shared Google Team Drive.

```
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'folder_id_goes_here' in parents"}).GetList()
```

I tried appending arguments like 'team_drive_id' = team_drive_id_goes_here and 'supports_team_drive' = True, but I'm not sure if I'm adding these on correctly.

```
team_drive_id = 'team_drive_id_goes_here'

file_list = drive.ListFile({
     'q': "'folder_id_goes_here' in parents",
     'supportsTeamDrives': True,
     'teamDriveId' = team_drive_id
}).GetList()
```

When I add these arguments to the ListFile function, I end up getting a 'googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403' error.

Does anyone know how to modify this query to work with folders in shared team drives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to propose the following modification.

#### From:

```
team_drive_id = 'team_drive_id_goes_here'
file_list = drive.ListFile({
     'q': "'folder_id_goes_here' in parents",
     'supportsTeamDrives': True,
     'teamDriveId' = team_drive_id
}).GetList()
```

#### To:

```
team_drive_id = 'team_drive_id_goes_here'
file_list = drive.ListFile({
    'q': "'folder_id_goes_here' in parents",
    'supportsAllDrives': True,  # Modified
    'driveId': team_drive_id,  # Modified
    'includeItemsFromAllDrives': True,  # Added
    'corpora': 'drive'  # Added
}).GetList()
```

or

```
file_list = drive.ListFile({
    'q': "'folder_id_goes_here' in parents",
    'supportsAllDrives': True,  # Modified
    'includeItemsFromAllDrives': True,  # Added
}).GetList()
```

#### Note:

- [The official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list) says `Warning: This item is deprecated.` for `includeTeamDriveItems` and `teamDriveId`. So in this case, please use `includeItemsFromAllDrives` and `driveId`, respectively.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)